# Activecollab htaccess convert to Caddyfile

Tags: .htaccess, routes, activecollab, caddy, caddyfile

please help with converting the htaccess file into caddyfile. We tried it with self-help but unsuccessfully. Can you look at it and help? Thank you

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

  RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ public/assets/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^wallpapers/(.*)$ public/wallpapers/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^verify-existence$ public/verify.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^proxy.php$ public/proxy.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^api/v([0-9]*)/(.*)/?$ public/api.php?path_info=$2&api_version=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^$ public/router.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) public/router.php?path_info=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```